# How do I enable and use placeholders in connectors using CSV import of diagrams.net

Tags: draw.io

I have a diagram I'm building using CSV. I've figured out how to user placeholders in shape labels. However I would like to also be able to use placeholders in the connections. I noticed that after I import what I already have, the connection objects don't have the `Placeholder` setting enabled in the `Edit Data` section. Is there a way to enable it from the `connect` json? I guess a follow up question would be to also how to set custom `data` to the connection.

My main goal for this question is so I can add to my connection label a sort of data-flow id possibly using the `from` and `to` so that it could be something like `DF1-2`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
## My Dataflow
# stylename: shapeType
# styles: { "docker-service": "shape=rectangle;html=1;fillColor=#dae8fc;strokeColor=#6c8ebf;"}
# labelname: labelType
# labels: { "process": "%name%<br><i style=\"color:gray;\">P%Pnum%</i>", \
#           "data-flow": "tls 1.2 %dataFlowNum%", \
#           "regular": "%name%"}
# identity: gid
# namespace: jay-
# parent: rparent
# parentstyle: shape=rectangle;html=1;dashed=1;align=left;verticalAlign=bottom;fillColor=#FFE6CC;strokeColor=#D79B00;
# connect: {"from":"refstls", "to":"gid", "invert":true, "label":"TLS v1.2", "style":"curved=0;endFill=1;fontSize=11;endArrow=blockThin;endFill=1;"}
# width: auto
# height: auto
# padding: 15
# nodespacing: 40
# levelspacing: 100
# edgespacing: 40
# layout: auto
## CSV starts under this line
gid,name,rparent,Pnum,labelType,shapeType,refstls
0,Network,,,regular,docker-service,,
1,docker ingress,0,1,process,docker-service,,
2,service1,0,2,process,docker-service,1,
3,service2,0,3,process,docker-service,1
4,service3,0,4,process,docker-service,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going over the CSV example comments that explained the connector and noticed something I missed the other day that seems to do what I want it to with limitations.

The `tolabel` and `fromlabel` can be used for what I wanted.

> optional fromlabel and tolabel can be used to name the column
>   that contains the text for the label in the edges source or target (invert ignored).

Solution based on my example would be:

```
## My Dataflow
# stylename: shapeType
# styles: { "docker-service": "shape=rectangle;html=1;fillColor=#dae8fc;strokeColor=#6c8ebf;"}
# labelname: labelType
# labels: { "process": "%name%<br><i style=\"color:gray;\">P%Pnum%</i>", \
#           "data-flow": "tls 1.2 %dataFlowNum%", \
#           "regular": "%name%"}
# identity: gid
# namespace: jay-
# parent: rparent
# parentstyle: shape=rectangle;html=1;dashed=1;align=left;verticalAlign=bottom;fillColor=#FFE6CC;strokeColor=#D79B00;
# connect: {"from":"refstls", "to":"gid", "invert":true,"fromlabel":"Pnum","tolabel":"Pnum", "label":"-", "style":"curved=0;endFill=1;fontSize=11;endArrow=blockThin;endFill=1"}
# width: auto
# height: auto
# padding: 15
# nodespacing: 40
# levelspacing: 100
# edgespacing: 40
# layout: auto
## CSV starts under this line
gid,name,rparent,Pnum,labelType,shapeType,refstls
0,Network,,,regular,docker-service,,
1,docker ingress,0,1,process,docker-service,,
2,service1,0,2,process,docker-service,1,
3,service2,0,3,process,docker-service,1
4,service3,0,4,process,docker-service,1
```

The main downside of this method is that "invert" is not taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

at the moment, diagrams.net doesn't support that but feel free to vote and track this feature request here:
https://trello.com/c/y9IAQ9kJ/96-allow-custom-data-on-connections-when-importing-csvs

Thanks,